# Storybook: Clicking a button redirects user

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, storybook

I have a link component that I want to display in Storybook. I'm using Vue.

This is the component
`NavigationLink.vue`:

```
<ul>
    <li :class="{selected: isSelected}">
        <a :href="linkUrl">
            <i :class="'isax isax-' + linkIcon"></i>
            {{ linkName }}
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This is the story `NavigationLink.stories.js`:

```
import NavigationLink from '../app/javascript/components/NavigationLink.vue'

export default {
    title: 'Navigation/Links',
    component: NavigationLink,
    argTypes: { ...argTypes here... }
}

const Template = (args) => ({
    components: { NavigationLink },
    setup() {
        return { args };
    },
    template: '<NavigationLink v-bind="args"></NavigationLink>',
});

export const UnselectedLink = Template.bind({});
UnselectedLink.args = { ...args here... }

export const SelectedLink = Template.bind({});
SelectedLink.args = { ...args here... }
```

Unfortunately, you're still able to 'click' the link in Storybook and this then redirects to the 'Introduction' page within Storybook. But I don't want it to redirect there at all. In fact, if possible, I'd prefer to not be able to click it at all.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I couldn't find a fancy way of doing this, so I just set the `:href` prop to be `linkHref: '/?path=/story/navigation-links--unselected-link'` in the args for `UnselectedLink` (and then similar for the `SelectedLink`). This still allows for the link to be clicked but will just redirect you back to the same story within Storybook.